# Remote connection to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have just installed Postgresql 9.1 on windows server 2008. I was trying to connect it from the remote computer on the default port 5432(as I have not changed it), but was not successful. So what are the possible configuration settings changes to made?

Comment: Is Windows Firewall getting in the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update some configuration files. They will be in a sub directory of your postgresql install in the data directory.  On Windows most likely `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data`

1. You need to update your `postgres.conf` file to `listen_addresses = '*'` so the postgres service can be seen by other machines. See [18.3. Connections and Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html).
2. To let any machine connect to postgres `pg_hba.conf`. The `0.0.0.0/0` says let any ip address connect. You can trim this down so it's only ip ranges on your network. See [19.1. The pg_hba.conf File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

   ```
   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Postgresql Configuration file.

Verify the setting for listen_addresses.  By default it likely only listens on your loopback address which would not allow you to connect from another machine.  The simplest way to get it listening on an external interface is to set it to:  `listen_addresses = '*'`

More info can be found in the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html).

Comment: and then the 'pg_hba.conf' rules